# How to remove the queries info in the page for Django

Tags: django

I would like to remove the queries information from the website. I am using django-html5-boilerplate.

The queries keeps appearing in the end of the page like this:

[image]

How can i remove this? It is very irritating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official or centralized django-html5-boilerplate package, but based on your problem, I'm guessing you're using [the one created by mike360 on github](https://github.com/mike360/django-html5-boilerplate)

If that's the case, in [base.html](https://github.com/mike360/django-html5-boilerplate/blob/master/projectname/templates/base.html), you'll find there the following bit of code:

```
{% if debug %}{% include 'includes/debug.html' %}{% endif %}
```

Setting `DEBUG=False` will make it go away (which you'll *have* to do in production, so you'll still need to solve that staticfiles problem), but if you simply don't want to see it during development, remove it from the template.

Comment: It worked but can you explain removing that line helps? interested to know why how it helps instead just it helps....

Comment: You'd have to look at the contents of `includes/debug.html`, as all that line does is include that template on the page. Most likely it uses the `{% debug %}` tag, which prints various information about the request and queries generated to the page.